# Cannot Deserialize xml to List<T>

Tags: c#, xml, list, xmlserializer

Im trying to deserialize this xml response of wcf web service to List using XmlSerializer but it fails with exception message :**There is an error in XML document (1, 2)**

xml:

```
<ArrayOfNote xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NotebookService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Note>
    <Author>Redouane</Author>
    <Body>Test note</Body>
    <CreationDate>2014-01-28T00:00:00</CreationDate>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Title>Hello World</Title>
  </Note>
</ArrayOfNote>
```

c#:

```
public class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the code i wrote to deserialize the received stream

```
private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
private List<Note> notes = new List<Note>();
```

.
.
.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Note>));
var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
List<Note> list = serializer.Deserialize(responseData) as List<Note>;
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the creation of serializer as follows and it should work.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Note>), 
                                new XmlRootAttribute("ArrayOfNote") { 
                                    Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NotebookService" 
                                });
```